# Javascript inheritance : How prototype chain works between native prototypes

Tags: javascript, function, object, inheritance, prototype

As we know everything in Javascript inherits from `Object`:

[image: Inheritance]

So if I create an object using constructor function like below:

```js
function Rabbit() {
  this.color = 'White'
}

let obj = new Rabbit();

alert(Rabbit.__proto__ === Function.prototype)       //true
alert(obj.__proto__ === Rabbit.prototype)            //true       
alert(obj.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype)  //true

alert(Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype)  //false
alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object))  //true
```

The first 3 results make sense because `obj` inherits from `Rabbit` function which itself inherits from `Function`. But if `Function` inherits from `Object` then why is the 4th result `False`. Also why do both `Object` and `Function` have same prototype (last result)?

Can someone explain this behavior. Am i missing something here?

Comment: All (most of) the objects in your diagram inherit (indirectly) from `Object.prototype`, not from `Object`.

Comment: `Object` and `Function` are just like the `function f(args) { … }` in your diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems like this are better explained with images (like the one in your question):

[image]

```
Legend:

   blue color = objects
   {} = simple object (+constructor name)
   Ⓟ = prototype object (+constructor name)

   magenta color = functions (ƒ + function name)
```

Basically, the `__proto__` chain for functions is:

```
concrete function (e.g. Rabbit, Object or Function itself) 
-> abstract function (aka Function.prototype) 
-> Object.prototype 
-> null
```

Comment: Wow thanks. That's a lot of valuable info in one picture. Can you comment on the parts a bit more. For example what is `f Object` vs `P Object` and similarly for Rabbit `{} Rabbit`, `f Rabbit` and `P Rabbit`. Also, what is the `f` here?

Comment: `f` and magenta color are functions, blue color are objects, `(P)` are objects that are prototypes,  `{}` is a simple object. `null` is null ;)

Comment: @VSX: the part after the `ƒ` is the function name. Just `ƒ` is a function without a name (anonymous). Your expression corresponds to two arrows from `ƒ Object __proto__` and `ƒ Function __proto__` to the anon function

Comment: The ultimate resource for questions like this is the standard: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0 . It's not particularly user-friendly, but it does contain all the answers.

Comment: Don't wanna sound nit picky but i find that website really confusing. Can't even search for a particular keyword (the search on the top left doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 3):

```
alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)) // true
```

Both `Function` and `Object` are functions, their prototype is `Function.prototype`. Can be verified with

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype // true
```

This very object was used to create the prototype of `Function` function, thus

```
Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype // true
```

rather than

```
Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype // false
```

```js
alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype)
alert(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype)
alert(Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype)
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re confusing `Function.__proto__` (and equivalently `Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)`), the prototype of the function constructor, with `Function.prototype.__proto__`, the prototype of functions.

```js
function Rabbit() {
  this.color = 'White'
}

let obj = new Rabbit();

console.log(Rabbit.__proto__ === Function.prototype)       //true
console.log(obj.__proto__ === Rabbit.prototype)            //true       
console.log(obj.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype)  //true

console.log(Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype)  //true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype))  //false
```